# What type of media server software do I need to transcode in near real time?

Tags: video, media, transcoding

Can anyone help me find a software stack for doing near real time video encoding/transcoding?

I want to allow users to upload videos(wmv, avi, mov, flash video, other formats) to my website. As soon as the file is uploaded, I want to encode/transcode it into h.264 (preferably with an API so I can get progress percentage etc) so that I can then play it back via html5 or a flash player.

Anyone have any guidance for me on this?

Oh, and the server platform can be either windows or linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use ffmpeg, it has a command line utility and also a few APIs if you want to the encoding programmatically

http://ffmpeg.org/